# How to Separate a string to multiple parts

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have some Persian text (*direction* `rlt`) that I want to separate them.

**Example:**

```
$str =" کامپیوتر : وسیله ی الکتریکی است 1.ماوس 2.کیبورد
       و مانیتور 3. کیس
چاپگر: وسیله ای است برای پرینت بر روی معمولا کاغذ
موبایل : نوعی تلفن است به صورت سیار و بی سیم
که جدیدا خیلی هم رایج شده است
و اکثر انسان ها دارند
خانه : محلی برای زندگی است. 1. حیوانات 2. انواع انسان ها
برای خود خانه می سازند. ";
```

I want this output:

```
{
    arr[
       {
         word: "کامپیوتر",
         mean: "وسیله ی الکتریکی است 1.ماوس 2.کیبورد و مانیتور 3. کیس"  
       },

       {
        word: "چاپگر",
        mean: "وسیله ای است برای پرینت بر روی معمولا کاغذ"
       },

       {
        word: "موبایل",
        mean: "نوعی تلفن است به صورت سیار و بی سیم که جدیدا خیلی هم رایج شده است و اکثر انسان ها دارند"
       },

       {
        word: "خانه",
        mean: "محلی برای زندگی است. 1. حیوانات 2. انواع انسان ها برای خود خانه می سازند."
       }
      ]
}
```

Well, I think I can't just use `explode(":", $str)`. Because the mean of word is not contestant, it is sometimes in several lines. I think I need to regex. So how can I do that?

---

**Edit:** An English example:

```
$str = "apple : it is a fruit
       computer : 1.an electronic device for storing and 
        processing data typically in binary form 2. according to
        instructionsgiven to it in a variable program"
        wall: a continuous vertical brick or stone structure
        that encloses or divides an area of land. 1. on the
       wall 2. brick wall 3. climbing wall";
```

I want this output:

```
{
    arr[
       {
         word: "apple",
         mean: "it is a fruit"  
       },

       {
        word: "computer",
        mean: "1.an electronic device for storing and processing data typically in binary form 2. according to instructionsgiven to it in a variable program"
       },

       {
        word: "wall",
        mean: "a continuous vertical brick or stone structure that encloses or divides an area of land. 1. on the wall 2. brick wall 3. climbing wall"
       }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you derive "word" and "mean?" An English language example would help me out if you have oen

Comment: @ExplosionPills I added an English example.

Comment: Split would be just as good as a regex. That is unless you have a distinct requirement, like the _`word :`_ must be the first on a newline.

Comment: Why aren't you including the `2.` for `$str` though?

Comment: Check [`'~\h*(?<term>[^:\n]*?)\s*:\s*(?<mean>(?:(?!\n\h+[^\n:]*:).)*)~us'`](http://ideone.com/0WzcQ0).

Comment: @ExplosionPills are you talking about EN or FA (persian) example? an which word?

Comment: @sln No, I'm sure `explode()` isn't fine.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks ...

Comment: @stack: Does it work with Persian? Please check [this code demo](http://ideone.com/WeF1Rs). If yes, I will post. This is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ5jD5/1).

Comment: @stribizhev I checked, It works as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
'~\h*(?<term>[^:\n]*?)\s*:\s*(?<mean>(?:(?!\n\h*[^\n:]*:).)*)~us'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ5jD5/1)

I am using the named capture groups so that you could access them easier later on. *Note that you need `/u` modifier to work with Unicode strings in PHP regex!*

The regex matches:

- `\h*` - 0 or more horizontal whitespace
- `(?<term>[^:\n]*)` - **Group 1** named "term" that matches 0 or more characters other than `:` and `\n`
- `\s*:\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces followed by `:` and zero or more whitespaces
- `(?<mean>(?:(?!\n\h*[^\n:]*:).)*)` - **Group 2** named "mean" that matches any characters (since I am using `/s` modifier) that are not starting a sequence like *spaces*+*term*+`:`. This `(?:(?!...).)*` construct is called a tempered greedy token. You can unroll this as [`(?<mean>[^\n]*(?:\n(?!\h*[^\n:]*:)[^\n]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ5jD5/2) for better performance (192 steps vs. 1226).

Use the regex with the `preg_match_all` rather than with `preg_replace` since you need an array:

```
$str =" کامپیوتر : وسیله ی الکتریکی است 1.ماوس 2.کیبورد
       و مانیتور 3. کیس
چاپگر: وسیله ای است برای پرینت بر روی معمولا کاغذ
موبایل : نوعی تلفن است به صورت سیار و بی سیم
که جدیدا خیلی هم رایج شده است
و اکثر انسان ها دارند
خانه : محلی برای زندگی است. 1. حیوانات 2. انواع انسان ها
برای خود خانه می سازند. ";
preg_match_all('~\h*(?<term>[^:\n]*?)\s*:\s*(?<mean>(?:(?!\n\h*[^\n:]*:).)*)~us', $str, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($m);
```

See the [code demo](http://ideone.com/WeF1Rs).

Answer (score 2):

This is a better way to do it.

This works but you have an extra step to do trimming of newlines in the *meaning*.

Just sit in a find loop. When you get a match, just run this replace on
the contents of *meaning* - group 2.
Then just store the results in an array.

Find:  `\s*\r?\n\s*`
Replace: " "

Main regex:

`(?m)^\h*([^:\r\n]*?)\h*:(.*(?:\s*^(?!\h*[^:\r\n]*?\h*:).*)*)`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 \h* 
 ( [^:\r\n]*? )                # (1) Word
 \h* :
 (                             # (2 start) Meaning
      .*  
      (?:
           \s* 
           ^          
           (?!
                \h* [^:\r\n]*? \h* :
           )
           .* 
      )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 8 ) 
کامپیوتر  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 11 , len 62 ) 
 وسیله ی الکتریکی است 1.ماوس 2.کیبورد
       و مانیتور 3. کیس  

---------------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 75 , len 5 ) 
چاپگر  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 81 , len 43 ) 
 وسیله ای است برای پرینت بر روی معمولا کاغذ  

---------------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 126 , len 6 ) 
موبایل  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 134 , len 90 ) 
 نوعی تلفن است به صورت سیار و بی سیم
که جدیدا خیلی هم رایج شده است
و اکثر انسان ها دارند  

---------------------

 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 226 , len 4 ) 
خانه  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 232 , len 76 ) 
 محلی برای زندگی است. 1. حیوانات 2. انواع انسان ها
برای خود خانه می سازند.
```

Comment: Actually, this is the _best_ way to do it !\